# Ignoring CSS :hover, :active, :focus declarations with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, yui, pseudo-class

I have a few links that when clicked, will open up a submenu. This is achieved by `:hover`, `:focus`, and `:active` declarations in my style sheet.

The effect is identical to this: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-click-flyout.html.

The thing is that while the CSS implementation works, there are various shortcomings, which I would like to fix with JavaScript. I am using [YUI 3.5.0](http://yuilibrary.com) as my javascript library. Is it possible to use JavaScript  to ignore the `:hover`, `:focus` and `:active` declarations in the stylesheet?

I am aware that I can put those declarations into a separate class and change the class of the element with JavaScript, but it doesn't seem very clean to me.

Comment: What you have said in your description is the solution, isolate using classes. And instead of using javascript to add/remove classes, it'll be better than changing the properties individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware that I can put those declarations into a separate class and change the class of the element with JavaScript, but it doesn't seem very clean to me.

That is as clean as it gets. A much less sanitary solution would be to duplicate the styles from your generic rules and inject them directly into your elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution with changing classes is the cleanest, but only for example you can override the hover with javascript:

With jQuery:

```
$('#js').hover(
    function() { $(this).css('color', 'blue'); },
    function() { $(this).css('color', 'black'); }
);
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8t2U/).

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('js').onmouseenter = function() {
    this.style.color = 'blue';
}
document.getElementById('js').onmouseleave = function() {
    this.style.color = 'black';
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8t2U/2/).

With YUI:

```
Y.one('#js').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.setStyle('color', '#00f');
});
Y.one('#js').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.setStyle('color', '#000');
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8t2U/3/).

Comment: I've added an YUI version to my answer.